# Rename a file at runtime with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file-rename

i try to rename a file using vb.net in this way:

```
my.computer.filesyste.rename(oldname,newname)
```

But if i use a software to recover files deleted, i find a file named :"_ldname", and if i  recovery the file "_ldname" i have, in this way, two files equals.
Can i do this without have a duplicate of my file?

Best regards 
 Sebastiano

Comment: Not sure if I understand your conditions, but you cannot have two files with the same name (the program would trigger an error). Please, describe your EXACT conditions properly (e.g., what means "if I recovery the file..."?)

Comment: i have do this: i have formatted a floppy disk, copied a file called myfile.txt and renamed with the command "my.computer.filesystem.renamefile(myfile.txt,newfile.txt), aftter i have modified the file (newfile.txt) and saved it. I read the floppy with "easyrecovery" and i have found a deleted file named (_yfile.txt) and recovered it. This file recovered contained the first version of the text. Now i have two files (with a different name) with two version of my text.

Comment: I have never seen this method of file copy used before in VB.NET. Have you tried using members of the System.IO namespace? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx

Comment: I guess that you can continue this conversation with StingyJack.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, this is a windows filesystem limitation and nothing to do with programming. Two files cannot have the same name in the same location.

The recovery software should be forcing a rename to Myfile(1).txt or something like that to distinguish between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use:

```
If File.Exists(path) = False Then
```

To make sure the file doesn't already exists. Then if it does exist you could add a "(1)" to the file name.

Comment: i know that cannot exisis two files with the same name in a directory, i only want to change name to a file, but the vb.net command duplicate my file, change name, and then delete the old file. So i have the old file deleted and the new file visible. Why? Thanks for your support. Sebastiano

Comment: Try this logic: Check if the file exists, then if it does rename the current file BEFORE recovering the lost file, then recover the lost file!

Comment: Correctly if i wont two file, but i wont only rename my file at Runtime using the command of vb.net, and i must find only 1 file in the floppy (or other), my question is why vb.net duplicate my file and do not change only the name in the fat table?